# Why am I getting a no attribute error in my python script but not in my python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-module, moviepy

I'm trying to write a program that edits a video using the moviepy module in python. I have this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import math
import moviepy as mp
import mediainfo

class Editor:

    OFFSET = 2 #seconds


    def __init__(self, identified_frames, options, *args, **kwargs):
        self.movie_path = options.video_path
        self.video = mp.editor.VideoFileClip(self.movie_path)
        #Get the FPS of the input movie and round the number up
        self.movie_fps = math.ceil(mediainfo.get_fps(self.movie_fps))
...
```

but for some reason this throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "editor.py", line 179, in <module>
    editor = Editor(args["video"], options)
  File "editor.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.video = mp.editor.VideoFileClip(self.movie_path)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'editor'
```

which is strange because according to [this](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/ukulele_concerto.html) documentation definitely exists. What is even weirder is that when I open up my python interpreter, I can do this with no problem:

```
In [1]: import moviepy

In [2]: import moviepy.editor

In [3]: import moviepy as mp

In [4]: mp.editor
Out[4]: <module 'moviepy.editor' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/moviepy/editor.pyc'>

In [5]: mp.editor.VideoFileClip
Out[5]: <class moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip.VideoFileClip at 0x1046bca10>
```

So the  `moviepy` module definitely contains `editor.VideoFileClip`. What would cause this error to be thrown in my program if it works in my interpreter? Do I have some environment variables set wrong or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've done:
I have python2 and python3 installed installed but made sure both the interpreter and the program were being run with python2. I also tried reinstalling moviepy but that didn't do anything. I also went and looked through the source code to make sure that the function actually existed (it does).

Update:

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696322/why-does-this-attributeerror-in-python-occur) question. The best answer says

> This happens because the scipy module doesn't have any attribute named
>   sparse. That attribute only gets defined when you import scipy.sparse.
>
> Submodules don't automatically get imported when you just import
>   scipy; you need to import them explicitly. The same holds for most
>   packages, although a package can choose to import its own submodules
>   if it wants to. (For example, if scipy/**init**.py included a
>   statement import scipy.sparse, then the sparse submodule would be
>   imported whenever you import scipy.)

Which leads me to change my question to why does python work this way? Is there a benefit?

Comment: maybe you named your file similar to names of modules and Python loads your file instead of modules.

Comment: @furas Isn't that what namespacing is there to protect against?