# AttributeError: module matplotlib has no attribute _tri

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, attributeerror

I am trying to use Matplotlib in my conda environment (Python 3.6) I am getting this error. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
   ....
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tri\triangulation.py in <module>()
  4 import six
  5 
----> 6 import matplotlib._tri as _tri
  7 import matplotlib._qhull as _qhull
  8 import numpy as np

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_tri'
```

Please let me know if I need to post more details of the error.

Comment: Dont you need to import numpy first?

Comment: it dosn't seen to be a numpy thing, that makes no difference

Comment: I had a similar issue when I was trying to do `import matplotlib` and then access `matplotlib.tri.triangulation.Triangulation` which resulted in an `AttributeError`. Running the following instead: `from matplotlib import tri; tri.triangulation.Triangulation` fixed the issue. This behavior was explained many times before, for example: [Why does this AttributeError in python occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696322/why-does-this-attributeerror-in-python-occur)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you have mismatched binaries, unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error because mine works.

(1): Perhaps try to uninstall matplotlib and then re-install it again

```
conda uninstall matplotlib

conda install matplotlib
```

(2) try the output `conda list` and `conda info` then analyze it or post it here maybe so we can analyze it?

(3) Try the following commands maybe they will work:

```
conda update --all
```

(4) if this doesn't work uninstall Anaconda maybe and try to reinstall the latest version of it.

Comment: I have re-installed it and that seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors may happen if you install different versions of the matplotlib package with `conda` and `pip`.  Uninstall both, i.e.`pip uninstall matplotlib` and `conda uninstall matplotlib`, and then install it from only one package manager, e.g. `conda install matplotlib`.