# How can I fix AttributeError in Manim Hello World program?

Tags: python, runtime-error, dependency-management, manim

I am attempting to write a Hello World program in Manim.

I have installed Manim and its prerequisite programs, and can run the sample code from the command prompt as intended.  This sample code operates in an unusual way; the user issues a command specifying not only a .py file, but also a single class within it, and Python executes the class definition code, seemingly without instantiating the class.

Now I'm trying to write a standalone .py file that works by instantiating a class when run (I am running it in Visual Studio Community 2019), rather than requiring external commands.

I have checked many of the Similar Questions, but unfortunately, they are all about Hello World programs in general, even spanning many non-Python languages.

I found a few AttributeError: '____' object has no attribute '____' questions in search, including this helpful explanation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696339/2364796), but nothing that seems to apply to the code I've explicitly written.

I also checked in IRC, and it was suggested that the problem is triggered within the imported code.  However, the same code functions properly when imported into the sample, so I must be working with it incorrectly.

This is the current code for my Hello World program.

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class GreetingScript(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        characters = TextMobject("Hello World!")
        self.add(characters)

scene1 = Scene()
readthrough = GreetingScript(scene1)
```

This is the error message produced by the above code.

```
Media will be stored in ./media\. You can change this behavior by writing a 
diff
erent directory to media_dir.txt.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 
2019\Projects\PythonApplication1\
PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 8, in <module>
    scene1 = Scene()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PortableApps\manim-0.1.5\manimlib\scene\scene.py", 
line 3
7, in __init__
    self, **self.file_writer_config,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PortableApps\manim- 
0.1.5\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer
.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.init_output_directories()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PortableApps\manim- 
0.1.5\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer
.py", line 49, in init_output_directories
    output_directory = self.output_directory or 
self.get_default_output_director
y()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PortableApps\manim- 
0.1.5\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer
.py", line 80, in get_default_output_directory
    filename = os.path.basename(self.input_file_path)
AttributeError: 'SceneFileWriter' object has no attribute 'input_file_path'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would expect the output of the program to be a display of the text "Hello World!" but the actual output is AttributeError: 'SceneFileWriter' object has no attribute 'input_file_path' accompanied by the rest of the above message.

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\jainil\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~-mpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.IPBC74C7KURV7CB2PKT5Z5FNR3SIBV4J.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: i cant even install manim

Comment: Yeah, it requires a few other programs.  I roughly followed Theorem of Beethoven's tutorial on Youtube, but used Visual Studio Community 2019 for my Python installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to remove the code that creates the `scene1` object. To make this code work, it is required to implement **only** the source of your scene class, and you can generate the scene using:

```
$ python -m manim -p /path/to/source.py GreetingScript
```

The `-p` flag means to open the video after rendering the scene. I hope this can help on your issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
from big_ol_pile_of_manim_imports import *

class makeText(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        #######Code#######
        #Making text
        first_line = TextMobject("Manim is fun")
        second_line = TextMobject("and useful")
        final_line = TextMobject("Hope you like it too!", color=BLUE)
        color_final_line = TextMobject("Hope you like it too!")

        #Coloring
        color_final_line.set_color_by_gradient(BLUE,PURPLE)

        #Position text
        second_line.next_to(first_line, DOWN)

        #Showing text
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Write(first_line), Write(second_line))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(FadeOut(second_line), ReplacementTransform(first_line, final_line))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Transform(final_line, color_final_line))
        self.wait(2)
```

have you tried something?

Comment: This code might be outdated, as big_ol_pile_of_manim_imports is no longer in use.  Furthermore, like the sample code, it doesn't instantiate makeText so would require a special command prompt "call" I think.